# Contactenat two String in one Response

Tags: java, servlets, response, runtimeexception

I want to concatenate `two String` in `one response`. I'm doing it like this:

```
String ch1 = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(val1).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                .build().getEntity().toString();

        String ch2 = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(val2).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                .build().getEntity().toString();


        Response res = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(ch1+"\n"+ch2).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).build();

        return res;
```

But I'm getting this exception on its execution

```
Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: input: application.ApplicationType@5172c28d
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: input: application.ApplicationType@5172c28d
application.ApplicationType@4542e0c1, indent: 2
    client.APIClient.prettyFormat(APIClient.java:295)
    client.APIClient.doPost(APIClient.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

**Can anyone tell me where the issue is?**

Comment: You can try `entity(val1+"\n"+val2)` instead of `entity(ch1+"\n"+ch2)`.

Comment: @KrutiPatel I obtain the same exception

Comment: Look at `client.APIClient.prettyFormat(APIClient.java:295)`, there seems to be the origin of your exception.